# Change MX record - separate mailserver from webserver

Tags: web-hosting, page-speed, mx

Ok, we all encountered at least one request to change MX entry and separate mailserver from webserver. That's all fine, we all know how to do it.

My problem here is this... let's say I put a site on shared hosting with 1GB free space. Occupation of resources is somewhere around maximum. 1018MB/1024MB used. Would mailserver slow down webserver and impact on web site speed?

Are thoose two separated although I'm on shared 1GB hosting, would this near quota disk usage have anything to do with webpage?

Comment: Your **title** and intro paragraph are about changing MX records and separating the mail and web servers - however, this does not appear to be related to your actual question?

Comment: It's on topic because I'm asking are those two separated although I'm on shared 1GB hosting. I'm concerned about mailserver and webserver that are stored on 1GB hosting package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What is bandwidth

In its most basic definition, bandwidth describes the level of traffic and data allowed to travel and transfer between your site, users, and the Internet. Each web hosting company will offer a particular level of bandwidth. This is often a good indication of which hosting companies have the best of three essential components: Networks, connections and systems.

Usually, the more bandwidth a web host can provide, the faster and the better these three factors will be.  At the same time, you should try to avoid attractive-looking “unlimited bandwidth” offers, as these are often not what they seem (more on this point later). “Unmetered bandwidth” should be more along the lines of what you are looking for.

## Bandwidth and the Relationship With Web Traffic

Let’s use another analogy to help make bandwidth clearer. In this example, the bandwidth is the number of tables in a restaurant, and the web traffic is the diners. The math is simple: The more tables in the restaurant, the more patrons can dine there at any one time.

## My Opinion

So generally it does impact on your page performance, and especially the load time of your website, in my opinion.

Also separating your mail server from your web server may be a good decision when you get into situation of receiving 70000 spam mails in the frames of 1 hour, because spam mails are quite common.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much mail you are sending/receiving. Also, shared hosting providers usually have hourly limits on how much mail you can send.  Somewhere around 500-1000 emails.  You better check up on it.  Tell them your issues, and needs.  Let them suggest the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The quota should not slowdown the performance of your website. Even if both are on the same server, it shouldn't affect the website performance. If you face problems with loading speed, I would suggest you to check with the provider. They should be able to investigate it further.